# How to empty the repository using push github

Tags: git, github, commit

I encountered with troubles in github. When I enter my valid credentials it asks me to enter the code I received on my email.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that I have forgotten my email password and cannot recover it.

I still can push commits. Now I would like to make the repositories I have empty. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'make the repositories I have empty'? Do you mean deleting them from GitHub?

Comment: @AndrewFan 
No, just combine all commits of my master branch into one to delete the history of commits. Then I would like to add a readme.md with the description of that pity situation

Comment: Better contact GitHub support and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some instructions, but before you do anything, **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE BACKUPS OF EVERYTHING**.

To delete a remote branch at `origin` (assuming `origin` is github):

```
git push origin :my-branch
```

You should also be able to delete `master` that way.

Then you can create a new branch, `master-alternative` as follows:

```
git checkout -b master-alternative <hash>
```

where  is the hash of the *first commit ever* on the master branch.

Then:

```
git rm -r .
echo "Sorry, I forgot my password" > README.md
git add README.md
git commit --amend # make this change part of the first commit rather than a new commit
git push --force origin master-alternative:master # push current branch to origin under the name 'master', --force in case you were unable to delete 'master' previously
```